# Are integrals in Riemann-Lebesgue theorem Riemann or Lebesgue

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Riemann-Lebesgue theorem says that if $f$ is Lebesgue-integrable on $\mathbb R$ that

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx=0.
\end{equation}

Are integrals $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\cos(nx)\,dx$ Riemann improper integrals or Lebesgue integrals? If they are Riemann, why do they exist?

Comment: They have to be interpreted as Lebesgue integrals, because $f$ is only assumed Lebesgue integrable.

Answer (score 3):

Only assumption on $f$ is : $f\in L^1$. Thus obviously the integral is Lebesgue integral.